# Developing a distributed system as a grid

Tags: grid, distributed-computing

Has anyone had experience with developing a distributed system as a grid?

By grid, I mean, a distributed system where all nodes are identical and there is no central management, database etc.

How can the grid achieve even distribution of: CPU, Memory, Disk, Bandwidth etc.?

Comment: like peer to peer? (torrent?)

Answer (score 2):

Something akin to [Plan9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9dist/) perhaps?

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) entry.

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually talking about is a cluster. There is a lot of software available for load balancing etc, even specific linux distros such as [Rocks](http://www.rocksclusters.org/wordpress/), which comes complete with MPI/PVM and monitoring tools built in.